# How to convert varchar column to datetime in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to compare between two dates in my sql request. I've found some similar questions but haven't been able to get anything to work yet.

I have a column Prev_Date as Varchar(250) where all the rows follow the `mm/dd/yyyy` format and I would like to convert it to date.

This is my request:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Final='0' AND
  DATE_ADD(Creation, INTERVAL Prevision MONTH) > SET DATEFORMAT Prev_Date
```

I tried this but didn't work.

Comment: That's not valid SQL. It's close though. Why does `SET` show up in the middle there?

Comment: So what is the correct one ?

Comment: Start with [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: Like this ? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Final='0' AND
  DATE_ADD(Creation, INTERVAL Prevision MONTH) > STR_TO_DATE('Prev_Date', '%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: I've removed `sql-server` tag. Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: When I use this, I am getting as records nothing, it is empty

Comment: Ideally you can alter your schema and have a proper `DATE` column instead of this arbitrary string. It will make queries like that significantly faster to execute, especially on large sets of data. Did that query work for you? That's the right idea.